# Virtual keyboard in Kiosk mode Raspberry Pi Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi3, kiosk-mode, virtual-keyboard

I´ve built an web application and I am running that on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian in KIOSK Mode. (10" touchscreen as well)

The idea is that it will be wall mounted with no keyboard or mouse attached to it. 
But the problem I have now is that I need some kind of virtual keyboard to either always show or only show on input focused.

I have tried with Matchbox-keyboard and I have changed the layout so it fit my needs, but when I try to run it in autostart it will only startup in a tiny tiny size in the corner.

I've also tried to manually start the keyboard and then start the browser in fullscreen but they do not want to play with each other.

So basicly I am wondering if anyone have any smart solution to fix my problem or if you can just recommend some other keyboard that might work.

Best Regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using -d option of matchboard-keyboard ....

mine working fine I am running chromium inside  nodm matchbox-window-manage over x11 here is my xsession file 
I Have to change layout  of keyboard like we have in most android...

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #Turn off Power saver and Screen Blanking 
    sleep 1;xset s off -dpms 
    sleep 1;xset s noblank 
    #sleep 1; xset s dpms 20 20

    # If Chrome crashes (usually due to rebooting), clear the crash flag so we don't have the annoying warning bar sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences sed -i 's/"exit_type":"Crashed"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences 
    matchbox-keyboard -d & 
    #Execute window manager for full screen 
    exec matchbox-window-manager -use_titlebar no &

    #Execute Browser with options 
    chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-pinch --kiosk --incognito file:///home/pi/mockup/index.html
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The way I have done it now is that I have only changed the autostart file so it will open chromium with its settings and start go to the specified url in kiosk mode. I have also tried to get matchbox WM to work but with no luck so far. I am not quite sure what the -d parameter does.. I´ve tried it within the autostart but then it only start when I close down kiosk mode and open the terminal(?). I would really appreciate some support on this matter. Best Regards, Daniel (can also add that I am kinda new to linux overall)

Comment: @Wahlstedt I am too new to linux.. follow this skip 4,5,6 step .... If you are on jessie lite install bellow packages for xserver
`sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg sudo apt-get install xinit 
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-fbdev` https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=940994#p9‌​71515

If you find any issue regarding kiosk chromium let me know I will try to answer here.....

Comment: Does this still work with Raspbian 9 and Chromium 72? I can make it work with Debian, but not on the Raspberry Pi using Raspbian.